# Why mongodb hangs after some time?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, amazon-web-services, tcp, mongodb

We have a problem with mongodb (3.6.3) PRIMARY server. After some time it gets to a state where it is still PRIMARY but it is not accepting connections. The problem is that it keeps PRIMARY role and because of that our app crashes. Mongodb restart on PRIMARY server helps and everything backs to normal.

We are hosting mongodb in Amazon on 3 Ubuntu m5.4xlarge instances with 3000 IOPS EBS volumes.

During the crash we have ~30% more connections to MongoDB than usual, but they are still far below the limits and far below fs.file-max setting that is set to 6430188. No other metric looks suspicious. RAM, CPU, Disk and Network usage are on the same level as just before crash and right after restart of PRIMARY. We have already migrate MongoDB from 3.4.14 to 3.6.3 and problem still occurs every 1-2 days. We have also changed priority for PRIMARY server and migrate this role to another host so it’s not connected to any specific machine.

There is nothing interesting on logs.

Here is the output of some commands that we run when the server was in not responsive state:

```
$ mongo -u root -p pass --authenticationDatabase admin --eval 'rs.status()'
MongoDB shell version v3.6.3
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
MongoDB server version: 3.6.3
2018-03-29T02:21:48.272+0000 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: network error while attempting to run command 'saslStart' on host '127.0.0.1:27017'  :
DB.prototype._authOrThrow@src/mongo/shell/db.js:1608:20
@(auth):6:1
@(auth):1:2

$ mongo -u root -p pass --authenticationDatabase admin --eval 'db.runCommand( { "connPoolStats" : 1 } )'
MongoDB shell version v3.6.3
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
MongoDB server version: 3.6.3
2018-03-29T02:21:48.272+0000 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: network error while attempting to run command 'saslStart' on host '127.0.0.1:27017'  :
DB.prototype._authOrThrow@src/mongo/shell/db.js:1608:20
@(auth):6:1
@(auth):1:2

$  mongo -u root -p pass --authenticationDatabase admin --eval 'db.runCommand( { serverStatus: 1 } )'
MongoDB shell version v3.6.3
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
2018-03-29T02:21:48.382+0000 W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, in(checking socket for error after poll), reason: Connection refused
2018-03-29T02:21:48.382+0000 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:251:13
@(connect):1:6
```

Any idea what else should we check to debug it?

Comment: How many open connections are there when the server stops responding?  Perhaps your app is opening connections, but never closing them causing the server to stop allowing new connections.  Take a peek by doing `netstat -an |grep :27017\\s |wc -l`

Comment: Number of open connections was around 3000. There ware times when we had ~5000 connections and mongo was working normally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that it was MongoDB bug that is fixed in newest MongoDB version. You can find full story in this [ticket](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-34190).

Answer (score 0):

I had issues with c5 instances hanging. It was running a very light web workload (no mongoDB) and I used to SSH to it for maintenance and it used to hang in 1-2 days where it was not accepting connections on 443 or SSH connections. I had to reboot it from AWS console and could see some disk issue in logs and also posted on AWS forum but no response. Also see below

https://www.reddit.com/r/aws/comments/7whfhn/new_nitro_based_m5c5_instances_seem_unstable/

Would recommend that you try m4 instances.

Comment: Yesterday we got back to m4 instance. We survived one night. It is still too soon to confirm that this is the cause.

Comment: It crashed also on m4 instance.